# How to find the value of k after the following pseudocode has been executed?

Tags: combinations, permutation, discrete-mathematics

What is the value of k after the following pseudocode has been executed?

```
k := 0
for i1 := 1 to n1
   k := k + 1
for i2 := 1 to n2
   k := k + 1
   ... 
for im := 1 to nm
   k := k + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT based on modified question]
Since the loops are NOT nested inside one another, each loop will simply increment k n_i times.
Therefore, the final value is

```
k = n1 + n2 + ... + nm
```

Comment: I made a mistake when I was writing out the code. The for loops are not nested. Would the final value be different?

Comment: Yes...equal to n1 + n2 ... nm